# How to sort namedtuple stored in dict value by tuple value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I stored namedtuple as value in a dictionary, like below

```
AssetList = {}
Asset = namedtuple('Asset_Desc', 'value weight value_per_unit')
for i in range(0,items):
    AssetList[i] = Asset(values[i], weights[i], values[i]/weights[i])
print AssetList
```

I would like to sort the dictionary based on "value_per_unit", so I wrote something like below. But I wonder what should be in 'key' ? I tried itemgetter and attrgetter, but it seems I got the index wrong, I can't figure out how to refer to Asset.value_per_unit. Any idea?

```
Sorted_AssetList = sorted(AssetList.iteritems(), key=???)
print Sorted_AssetList
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're sorting a key-value tuple that looks like `(1, asset)`, so you can use a function:

```
..., key=lambda pair: pair[1].value_per_unit)
```

Also, this doesn't seem like a good use for a dictionary. I would use a list instead:

```
Asset = namedtuple('Asset_Desc', 'value weight value_per_unit')

assets = []

for i in range(items):
    assets.append(Asset(values[i], weights[i], values[i]/weights[i]))
```

And sort the result of `enumerate()`, if you really do need the indices:

```
sorted_assets = sorted(enumerate(assets), key=lambda pair: pair[1].value_per_unit)
```

Otherwise, you can just use `attrgetter`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

sorted_assets = sorted(assets, key=attrgetter('value_per_unit'))
```

Comment: awesome!  I changed it to Sorted_Asset = sorted(AssetList.iteritems() , key=lambda (k,v): v.value_per_unit, reverse=True)  , so it's easier to ready by (key, value) instead of pair. Thanks!

Comment: @twfx: Sequence unpacking in function arguments was removed in Python 3 (although I do agree that it's useful for `lambda`s).

Comment: arh.... I did the "list" version too, hmmm... it seems like a better idea to move from dictionary to list. Thanks. I like your idea.